# Generalize Invoke function and delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

How can I factor those two function/delegate into one general function and delegate ?
Is there an easy way to do this ?

```
public TabControl tab;
public Label devlog;

delegate void tabHandlerCallback(bool e);
public void tabHandler(bool e)
{
    if (tab.InvokeRequired)
    {
        tab.Invoke(new tabHandlerCallback(tabHandler), new object[] { e });
    }
    else
    {
        tab.Enabled = e;
    }
}

delegate void devHandlerCallback(string e);
public void devHandler(string e)
{
    if (devlog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        devlog.Invoke(new devHandlerCallback(devHandler), new object[] { e });
    }
    else
    {
        devlog.Text = e;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the types of `tab` and `devlog`?

Comment: I edited my post and added their declaration

Comment: If these are handlers for events from a winform form just use the designer to connect the event to the same handler (pick one of them) and delete the code for the other handlers

Comment: If you use tools developed after 2002, such as BackgroundWorker or (ideally) `await` to manage your work (which if you can't, you have some pretty big problems on your hands), then you'll never have a need to explicitly invoke in the first place.  Also, if you're in a situation where you don't know whether or not you're on the UI thread *you have done something horribly, horribly wrong* in the design of your program.  You show know *at compile time*, which methods need to be run from the UI thread and which from a non-UI thread.  That *radically* improves the ability to read and maintain it.

Comment: I found the solution and posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it :

```
delegate void controlHandlerCallback(object control, object param, string field = "Text");
public void controlHandler(object control, object param, string field="Text")
{
    if (((Control)control).InvokeRequired)
    {
        ((Control)control).Invoke(new controlHandlerCallback(controlHandler), new object[] { control, param,field });
    }
    else
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = control.GetType().GetProperty(field);
        propertyInfo?.SetValue(control, param);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code

```
public delegate void InvokeDelegate();

//T_Elapsed is a thread and controls required invoke
private void T_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(InvokeMethodLabel));
    this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(InvokeMethodProgressBar));
}
void InvokeMethodLabel()
{
    myLabel.Text = "Test Label";
}
void InvokeMethodProgressBar()
{
    progressBar.Value = (int)(progressBar.Value * 2);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make a function that can run the necessary code either directly, or by invoking.

```cs
private void InvokeIfNecessary(Control control, Action action)
{
    if(control.InvokeRequired)
        control.Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
}

// use it like this
public void devHandler(string e)
{
    InvokeIfNecessary(() => devlog.Text = e);
}

public void tabHandler(bool e)
{
    InvokeIfNecessary(() => tab.Enabled = e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you think it's possible to factor also the two handler function with a ref ?

Comment: Also can you explain the parameters you use in the Handlers, I don't get how to use them